# Pass Value and Position of a Button to Outside Function OnClick/Delegate

Tags: javascript

How can I pass the value and position of the button onChange event to an outside function. I have the following code but I can't get it working.

```
$(".holder").delegate(".selectQuantity", 'change', function() {
   handleSelection(this);
});

function handleSelection(this) {
   let itemId = $(this).val();
   let itemName= $(this).closest('.item').find('.itemName').text();
};
```

Comment: Don't name any variables or parameters `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event parameter of the handler to retrieve the target

```js
$(".holder").delegate(".selectQuantity", 'change', function(e) {
   handleSelection(e.target);
});

function handleSelection(inputElmt) {
   let itemId = $(inputElmt).val();
   // ...
};
```

Note: like already said in comments, don't name your variables or parameters `this` because it's a reserved keyword.